# Bibliography within table of contents in report class

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I am trying to insert the bibliography in the TOC, and I am using the `report` document class. After looking at similar questions in this forum, I found that this code is what appears to work best:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[section, numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage{titlesec}   
\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontsize{14}{16}\bfseries \selectfont}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\fontsize{13}{16}\bfseries \selectfont}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\fontsize{12}{16}\bfseries \selectfont}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Overview and Epidemiology}
\subsection{Complications}
\subsection{Maternal Medical Complications}
\subsection{Obstetric Maternal Complications}
\subsection{Fetal and Neonatal Complications}
\subsection{Diabetes and Urogenital Tract Infections}
\subsection{Diabetes and Menarchal Irregularities}
\subsection{Psychology and Diabetes}
\subsection{Prevention, Treatment and Prognosis}
\section{Aim of the Study}
\section{Materials and Methods}
\section{Results}
\subsection{Socio-Economic level and regional origin}
\subsection{Anthropometric characteristics}
\subsection{Therapy}
\subsection{Utenza ambulatoriale}
\subsection{Gynecologic history}
\subsection{Obstetric information}
\subsection{Contraception}
\section{Discussion}
\bibliography{Libreria_personale}
\end{document}
```

However, the output file gives me a redundant "Contents" line which I don't know how to eliminate.

[image]

I've seen that with the `documentclass{scrartcl}` it is possible to create the output I desire, however I would like to keep using the `report` class.
I've tried to change the code into:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*}{\section}{}{}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\section{\bibname}}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage{titlesec}   
\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontsize{14}{16}\bfseries \selectfont}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\fontsize{13}{16}\bfseries \selectfont}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\fontsize{12}{16}\bfseries \selectfont}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Overview and Epidemiology}
\subsection{Complications}
\subsection{Maternal Medical Complications}
\subsection{Obstetric Maternal Complications}
\subsection{Fetal and Neonatal Complications}
\subsection{Diabetes and Urogenital Tract Infections}
\subsection{Diabetes and Menarchal Irregularities}
\subsection{Psychology and Diabetes}
\subsection{Prevention, Treatment and Prognosis}
\section{Aim of the Study}
\section{Materials and Methods}
\section{Results}
\subsection{Socio-Economic level and regional origin}
\subsection{Anthropometric characteristics}
\subsection{Therapy}
\subsection{Utenza ambulatoriale}
\subsection{Gynecologic history}
\subsection{Obstetric information}
\subsection{Contraception}
\section{Discussion}
\bibliography{Libreria_personale}
\end{document}
```

However, in the output file, the "Contents" heading is too big:

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `\section` constantly in a report, without `\chapter`? Why are you using `titlesec` for a ToC that does loc pretty much the same as the standard one. And you can get rid off `Contents` in the ToC by using the `nottoc` option to `tocbibind`. Concerning `scrartcl` and `titlesec`: Don't use both together!

Answer (score 2):

The `tocbibind` package offers the `nottoc` option to prevent the inclusion of `Contents` in the `ToC` itself -- I used the first code verson provided at the top in the OP.

I don't understand why only `sections` are used in this `report` file, as well as `titlesec` packag for rather 'standard' type of sectioning header formats. (... but that's not the question here ;-))

I strongly suggest to use the `article` class instead!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[section, numbib,nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\usepackage{titlesec}   
\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontsize{14}{16}\bfseries \selectfont}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\fontsize{13}{16}\bfseries \selectfont}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\fontsize{12}{16}\bfseries \selectfont}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Overview and Epidemiology}
\subsection{Complications}
\subsection{Maternal Medical Complications}
\subsection{Obstetric Maternal Complications}
\subsection{Fetal and Neonatal Complications}
\subsection{Diabetes and Urogenital Tract Infections}
\subsection{Diabetes and Menarchal Irregularities}
\subsection{Psychology and Diabetes}
\subsection{Prevention, Treatment and Prognosis}
\section{Aim of the Study}
\section{Materials and Methods}
\section{Results}
\subsection{Socio-Economic level and regional origin}
\subsection{Anthropometric characteristics}
\subsection{Therapy}
\subsection{Utenza ambulatoriale}
\subsection{Gynecologic history}
\subsection{Obstetric information}
\subsection{Contraception}
\section{Discussion}
\bibliography{Libreria_personale}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Christian, however I have the problem of the "Content" heading, which is too big.

Comment: @Luigi: It's the default setting of fontsize.

Comment: Ok, but I need to have it of the same size as the section headings